# Advice on sharding the Parse Server _User collection?

Tags: parse-server, sharding

The out-of-the-box _User collection in Mongo for Parse Server has a unique index on both username and email.  Given that, what's the ideal strategy for sharding this collection?  My initial plan was to just use _id (not hashed) but obviously that doesn't work with the unique indexes.

Answer (score -1):

You can shard it by `"_id": "hashed"`, but it will give the warning `Can't ensure unique email or username` or something of that sort.